# javascript server side listener on .txt change

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, qr-code

i have a script that keep listening change on txt file, via a cordova app i send qr code to a web service which write on a txt...for now i have a button that trigger to this:

```
jQuery.get('../QRDemoLog.txt', function(data) {

   alert(data);

});
```

it works...but sometimes even if the file is changed it alert the old qr code scanned...
i've also tried to load content on an hidden iframe:

```
function getQr(){
var asd=document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body.firstChild.innerHTML;

asd=asd.replace(/&lt;/g,"<");
  asd=asd.replace(/&gt;/g,">");


 alert("Ultimo Qr code inserito "+asd);

}
```

how can i do to keep tracking the changes on that .txt? (maybe refreshing page on tot second?)

Comment: Load text file as string. Store it, Load text file as string, compare operator to stored, action if different. Schedule it every X seconds.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Matt the Ninja i solved this way:

```
function getQr(){

jQuery.get('../QRDemoLog.txt', function(data) {

    if(window.qr==null){
    window.qr=data;
    alert("Ultimo qr inserito:  \n"+window.qr);
    }

   if(window.qr!=data){
    alert("Ultimo qr inserito:  \n"+data);
    window.qr=data;
   }

});

setTimeout(getQr, 900);

}
```

and in the ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...

setTimeout(getQr, 900);

});
```